# Calling action from within lock/semaphore

Tags: multithreading

I have a function which accepts an action. The function obtains a semaphore lock (but for the purposes of the question could also be a monitor lock) and then calls the action.

A code reviewer has stated *does not represent an effective way to implement thread-safety because it is prone to deadly embrace.  Thread-safe code should be encapsulated but you break this by allowing a third-party to invoke an external action.  (It's like raising an event inside a lock.)*

Ignoring the encapsulation bit, is there any special case with calling actions from with a lock? My instinct is to say an action is no more likely to incur a deadlock than any other code but before i challenge that, is he right??

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour), as it asks about *software design*. On Stack Overflow it is just `primary opinion-based` one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with calling external code when lock is acquired is that you *cannot guarantee* anymore that your code is deadlock-safe.

The caller can do anything in the callback action.
Here is a few examples when action might perform 'dangerous':

1. Recursive call of a function. Deadlock is possible in that case.
2. Perform some long running operation. That might downgrade the others threads performance if they need the same synch object (monitor or semaphore).

I believe there are the other negative cases also possible.

The purpose of a monitor (or a semaphore) is to *prevent simultaneous entering into the code section, which is definitely should not be run simultaneously*. That is not the case for the callback action.
So, there is no good reason to call action within the lock.

I would suggest here instead to call the callback action either before the lock is acquired or after it is released.

Comment: That's more related to design and responsibilities affiliated with the external action. The lock is manipulated via some handler so in order for it to be reacquired again (causing the deadlock) the handler must be available to the external action. This can be easily avoided - e.g., by simply not providing the lock handler to the function triggering the external action.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername private handler can be reacquired even if it is not visible for external code. Just second call of the function, which acquires it. That might be done from the callback action.

Comment: Nothing protects completely from bugs. To have a deadlock external action isn't really needed. For example,  you can simply make a recursive call to the executing function after acquiring the lock.

Comment: Well, external action - is the thing which is _out of control_. The locking function should be written so, that it is safe when recursive call is performed from the external callback action. That's why it is bad to call external code inside a lock.

Comment: Control is a matter of definition. Correct external action should have a set of prerequisites to comply with.  Safe recursive call depends on the type of locking mechanism used. If it's safe for local reentry it will be safe for reentry from external action (or direct lock reacquisition) and vice versa

Comment: Prerequisites. That's exactly what I'm suggesting to avoid. At least as many as possible. Usually they increase complexity and give more chances to make an error.

Comment: Prerequisites should be integral part of design. Minimizing them shouldn't be a target and serves no purpose on itself. You might be confusing them with dependencies.